# 1.13.7—Recursion Error through Nested Components

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am on `ember.js@1.13.7` and have created a nested component, which is three levels deep.

In Handlebars it looks like so:

```
//template that is rendered by the route, let's call it region-top.hbs

{{#component-level-one}}
  {{#component-level-two}}
    {{component-level-three}}
    {{component-level-three}}
    {{component-level-three}}
    {{component-level-three}}
  {{/component-level-two}}
{{/component-level-one}}
```

The templates of `component-level-one` and `component-level-two` are quite similar and look like that:

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
{{yield this}}
```

Running that whole thing gives me:

```
Uncaught: Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Without the `wrapping component-level-one` it works fine.

But the items are rendered. So this one is caused by some subsequent event. In both, `ComponentLevelTwo, and -Three`, I am using the `targetObject` Property, to delegate the events to the parent view like so:

```
targetObject: Em.computed.alias('parentView');
```

Any Idea?

**UPDATE**

I found the issue… I am not sure if that is at all ember related, since we use our own build system here. The error was caused because the file which contained `ComponentLevelOne` was just `ComponentLevelOne.js` not `ComponentLevelOneComponent.js`, changing that fixed the issue.

Comment: I'd prefer not using parentView as targetObject but writing it explicitly at templates.

Comment: @ykaragol could you give me an example? I have trouble using the `sendAction` method and your solution might probably be better…

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised your ember version is old. You cannot use closureActions or contextual components.